# Transparent Nav only working with fixed-top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want my Nav to be transparent, but not fixed. When it's not fixed, it pushes all the content below it, meaning the BG of the nav is then white. So, it no longer looks transparent. I need a non-fixed nav, to have the same effect as fixed-top, meaning, it doesn't push content down - but isn't fixed.

Example is below, if you add "fixed-top" into the nav, you'll see what I mean.

```css
.navbar {
 background-color: rgba(225,225,225, 0.4) !important;
 border-color:transparent;
 background-image:none;
 box-shadow:none; 
}
.jumbotron.massage {
background: url(https://mave.me/img/projects/full_placeholder.png) no-repeat center center;  
background-size: cover;
background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
height: 100vh;
width: 100%; 
color: white;
position: relative;
padding-top: 10rem;
overflow: hidden;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.jumbotron {
background: url(https://mave.me/img/projects/full_placeholder.png) no-repeat center center;  
background-size: cover;
background-blend-mode: darken;
background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.6);
height: 100vh;
width: 100%; 
color: white;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.jumbotron:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-2">
  <img class="navbar-brand" style="max-width: 325px; max-height: 200px;" src="img/centred3.svg">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Treatments
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gift Cards</a>
      </li>            
    </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Book Online</button>
  </div>
</nav>


        <div class="jumbotron massage">
            <div class="container">
             <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 text-center content">
                        <h1 class="mb-4">Service Therapy for only £32</h1>
                        <p class="mb-4">Whether your Place holder placeholder placeholder</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-4 animated slideInLeft">Reserve your Appointment</a>
                        <p class="arrow up"></p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><p style="margin-bottom:800px;"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav{    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: .navbar { *   Works though! Thanks.